# Why the Definability Lemma may fail for class forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

It is known that over GBC, the Definability Lemma may fail some class forcing $\mathbb{P}$. I'd like to understand why the usual way of defining $\Vdash$ doesn't work.

For example, we may naively define $p \Vdash \pi \in \tau$ by transifine recursion as follows.

$p \Vdash \pi \in \tau$ iff $\{q \leq p : \exists \langle \sigma, r \rangle \in \tau (q \leq r \land q \Vdash \pi = \sigma) \}$ is dense below $p$.

In Friedman's "Fine Structure and Class Forcing", the explanation of why this doesn't work is that since $\mathbb{P}$ is a proper class, the quantifier complexity of the definition may increase with the ranks of $\tau$ and $\pi$. But I don't understand this explanation. Why does the complexity of the quantifiers matter in this definition?

My own understanding is this. The definition uses a recursion on the class $\mathbb{P} \times \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{P}}$ ($\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{P}}$ is the forcing langauge), so this requires a set-like well-founded relation $R$ on $\mathbb{P} \times \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{P}}$. But whenever $\sigma$ is in the domain $\tau$, then for every $q \in \mathbb{P}$, we would want $(q, \pi = \sigma)$ to be below $(p, \pi \in \tau)$ in the sense of $R$. Thus, there may not be such $R$ because $\mathbb{P}$ is a properclass.

Is my understanding correct? If so, what is the relation between Friedman's explanation and mine?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is near correct. The problem about defining $p\Vdash \sigma=\tau$ is that it requires recursion on $\sigma$ and $\tau$, which is not available in general.

To state this problem more precise, let us state the defintion of $p\Vdash \sigma=\tau$:

> $p\Vdash \sigma=\tau$ iff the following holds:
>
> 1. For each $(\pi, s)\in\sigma$, the class of all $q\le p$ such that
>    $$q\le s\to \exists (\rho,r)\in\tau [q\le r\land q\Vdash \pi=\rho]$$
>    is dense below $p$.
> 2. Similarly, for $(\rho, r)\in\tau$, the class of all $q\le p$ such that
>    $$q\le r\to \exists (\pi,s)\in\sigma [q\le s\land q\Vdash \pi=\rho]$$
>    is dense below $p$.

The definition of $p\Vdash \sigma=\tau$, uniform to $p$, is done by recursion of the maximum of *forcing name rank* of $\sigma$ and that of $\tau$. (Forcing name rank is defined by $\operatorname{rank}_\mathbb{P}(\sigma)=\sup\{\operatorname{rank}_\mathbb{P}(\tau)+1\mid \tau\in\operatorname{dom}\sigma\}$. It does not gauge the rank given by forcing conditions.) In some sense, we need a class recursion of length $\mathrm{Ord}$.

However, $\mathsf{GBC}$ is not enough to carry over such definition. To address this issue, let me simplify what is going on there. Suppose $F(p,\sigma,\tau)$ be the relation $p\Vdash \sigma=\tau$, and let $F_\alpha(p,\sigma,\tau)$ be the relation $p\Vdash \sigma=\tau$ restricted to names whose forcing name rank is $\le\alpha$. By examining the above definition, we can find some first-order formula $\phi$ such that
$$F_\alpha = \{(p,\sigma,\tau)\mid \phi(p,\sigma,\tau,F_{<\alpha})\},$$
where $F_{<\alpha}$ is the forcing relation $p\Vdash \sigma=\tau$ restricted to names whose forcing name rank is $<\alpha$. The above form of recursion is known as *Elementary Transfinite Recursion* $\mathsf{ETR}$, and $\mathsf{ETR}$ is not provable over $\mathsf{GBC}$. In fact, $\mathsf{GBC+ETR}$ implies the consistency of $\mathsf{GBC}$.

We do not need the full strength of $\mathsf{ETR}$, though. Our transfinite recursion will be done at length $\mathrm{Ord}$, so what we need is the principle named by $\mathsf{ETR}_\mathrm{Ord}$:

> ($\mathsf{ETR}_\mathrm{Ord}$) Let $\phi(x,A,X)$ be an elementary formula. If we set $(X)_\alpha=\{y\mid (\alpha, y)\in S\}$ and $(X)^\alpha=\{(\beta,y)\in X\mid\beta<\alpha\}$, we can find a class $S$ such that
> $$(S)_\alpha = \{x \mid \phi(x,A,(S)^\alpha)\}$$
> for all ordinal $\alpha$.

That is, $\mathsf{ETR}_\mathrm{Ord}$ is sufficient to define the relation $p\Vdash \sigma=\tau$. Furthermore, it turns out that $\mathsf{ETR}_\mathrm{Ord}$ is optimal:

> ([Gitman-Hamkins-Holy-Schlicht-Williams](https://doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2019.89), Main Theorem) The definability of $p\Vdash\sigma=\tau$ for any class forcing $\mathbb{P}$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{ETR}_\mathrm{Ord}$.

Let me also note that defining the forcing relation for an atomic formula is the only problem because we define $p\Vdash\phi$ for any formula $\phi$ over the metatheory, and not over an object theory. That is, we do not have a uniform definition for $p\Vdash\phi$, but a definition schema that will give a definition of $p\Vdash\phi$ for each $\phi$.